# Setting default browser on Vista/Win7

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'd like to set a program as the 'default browser', so that for example, it'll be opened when addresses like `http://google.com/` are opened by another program or Windows.
At first I assumed this was the same as XP (via `HKCR`), but I found that you need to use the 'Default Programs' feature of Vista[+]. The relevant key is stored, I think, at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice`, but for me that's just 'FirefoxURL', which I assume maps to some larger key elsewhere.

How should this be done properly?

I've also found that you can use `IApplicationAssociationRegistration`, but there doesn't seen to be any .NET wrappers around it and I can't find out for the life of me how to go about using it.

Any information about how other programs do this or just hints in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically in the right place:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations`

The "gotcha" is that there are a bunch of subkeys you need to set:

- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_26679211.html
- http://forum.codejock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=13563&title=how-to-set-default-browser