# How to initialize Selenium driver for default web browser and os

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my program, We are creating selenium webdriver for firefox with linux operating system. I wanted to know if there is any way you can create the driver which will initalize for the default operating system and web browser.

```
   protected static WebDriver driver = init();



private static WebDriver init()
   {
      DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); // I want 
to detect the default browser of OS
      capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);//it should automatically find the OS.

  WebDriver driver = init(BrowserType.FIREFOX);//Same here for initializing default web browser.

  driver.manage()
        .deleteAllCookies();
  driver.manage()
        .timeouts()
        .pageLoadTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.manage()
        .timeouts()
        .implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.manage()
        .window()
        .maximize();
  return driver;
```

}

Comment: Are you asking this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852885/ question or something different?

Answer (score 0):

**To the best of my knowledge, the following options work on both Windows and Linux:**

Option #1 - open in Normal mode:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Option #1 - open in Headless mode:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("your/firefox/path"));
binary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY",System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id",":99"));
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,null);
```