# InstallAnywhere Readme files

Tags: hyperlink, installanywhere

I am using InstallAnywhere 2012. In the post-install section the installer is showing a readme . There are internal and external links in the  readme  file. The internal ones are not working(it is not navigating to the respective section of readme).

I tried to open the readme.html in a browser and there it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this in the shell, the syntax would look something like..

> "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file:///C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/index.html#anchor1"

here's one, admittedly crude, way to do that in IA:

> 1) employ a small jar program that finds browsers ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852885/method-returning-default-browser-as-a-string))
>
> 2) then your program will compose a couple of strings and write them to a .bat or .sh file - ie the command(s) string to open the browser and the string for your local readme
>
> 3) then your program can either pass the "special folder" back to IA using [custom code](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installanywhere2011/Content/helplibrary/ia_key_custom_code_vars.htm), or, for expediency, execute it directly if you don't care how it happens.
>
> 4) this produces a browser scrolled down to the right anchor.

the alternative actions of "open default browser", or "launch file", provided by IA api seems to strip (or not allow) the #anchor annotation in url's.