# Open URL with # from WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, url, browser

I need to open a URL that has a "#" inside using the default browser. I use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file:///c:\Projects\HTMLTest\Debug\help\index.htm#Modules\Administration\UserInterface\MainWindow\Processing.htm");
```

Now when the browser is launched but the URL it receives is

```
file:///c:\Projects\HTMLTest\Debug\help\index.htm
```

Everything after and including the # is cut off. What can I do to open the complete URL in the browser?

Comment: of course, the part after `#` is **invalid**, the part after `#` should be name of some `HTML Anchor tag` in the `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get path of executable of default browser from registry (look at the following answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599201/2870402) and create new process passing the URL as the parameter:

```
string pathToExecutable = ...;
string url = @"file:///c:\Projects\HTMLTest\Debug\help\index.htm#Modules\Administration\UserInterface\MainWindow\Processing.htm";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToExecutable, url);
```

Comment: Thanks. The referenced SO example works like a charm.