# How to determine if Microsoft Edge is the default browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is there a reliable, programmatic way to determine that Microsoft Edge is the default browser?

I know one option would be to use the  [IApplicationAssociationRegistration::QueryCurrentDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776336(v=vs.85).aspx) method to return the default application registered for http. It's unclear that the ProgID returned by this call is a fixed string though so it may not be the best way to verify that Edge is indeed the default browser.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code snippet.  Haven't tested with Firefox or any of the other strange ones, but you'll get the following return values based on your default browser in Windows 10.

- Chrome - ChromeHTML
- Edge - AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v
- Internet Explorer - IE.HTTP

Code snippet below should work.  Tested in a console app.  If anyone wants a VB version let me know.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
public static class BrowserUtils
{
    static public string GetSystemDefaultBrowser()
    {
        string _retval = string.Empty;
        const string userChoice = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice";
        using (RegistryKey userChoiceKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(userChoice))
        {
            if (userChoiceKey == null)
            {
                _retval = "unknown-> userChoiceKey returned null";
            }

            object progIdValue = userChoiceKey.GetValue("Progid");
            if (progIdValue == null)
            {
                _retval = "unknown->GetValue(Progid) returned null";
            }
            //_retval = String.Format("progId=[{0}]", progIdValue.ToString());
            _retval = progIdValue.ToString();
        }
        return _retval;
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa.

Comment: Yes, like the `IApplicationAssociationRegistration::QueryCurrentDefault` I mentioned, you end up with a ProgID for Edge -- the question is, is that ProgID reliable (not likely to change).

Comment: hitup the msft web working group on this.  I will 'nag' a week from now as well but don't be afraid to 'pingme' to renag.  worse comes to worse, we could setup a GitHub repo or gist with the values that edge has been/will be and do some weirdness around that.

Comment: darned if I can get an answer on whether this value changes or not.  i'll keep running the code locally and we can see if it changes over time.

Comment: as of today, it's still AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v