# Is there any way to receive callback to our custom exe when user changed default browser on windows?

Tags: c, windows

For example : I have my custom exe lets say "sample.exe". Assume firefox was my default browser on  windows 10, and now i changed it to google chrome.
So after changing default browser to google chrome, is there any way to register sample.exe to receive callback.

Comment: I would hope not.

Comment: Well, this is not a C programming question!!

Comment: You need to play with Windows registry in order to check which is the default browser, but regarding callback notification I am clueless...

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621467/how-to-find-default-web-browser-using-c) gives you a bit of hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register with the windows registry, identify the key that denotes the default browser and then set up a `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` callback. There is a number of possible variations on how a default browser can be set which is - due to the fact that you didn't exactly ask for that - probably too much to ask for inclusion in this answer. [Here](https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/) is a nice article on this topic.

This will call your code when something happens with the specified registry key.

Note this callback is not called on bulk changes to the registry - So depending on the method the default browser is changed, it might or might not be called.